# Bridge pattern - two examples comparison

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

I was wondering if both of examples (or neither of them) are bridge pattern. So the first one:

```
class ButtonImpl {
    public:
    virtual void click() = 0;
};

// concrete implementation
class ToggleButtonImpl : public ButtonImpl {
    public: 
    void click() {
        cout << "Push\n";
    }
};

// concrete implementation
class PushButtonImpl : public ButtonImpl {
    public: 
    void click() {
        cout << "Push\n";
        cout << "Pop\n";
    }
};

// abstraction
class Button {
    public: 
    Button(ButtonImpl* buttonImpl) : m_buttonImpl{ buttonImpl }
    {
    }
    void click() {
        m_buttonImpl->click();
    }
    
    private: 
    ButtonImpl* m_buttonImpl;
};
```

and the second one:

```
// implementation
class ButtonImpl {
    public:
    virtual void click() = 0;
};

// concrete implementation
class WindowsButtonImpl : public ButtonImpl {
    public:
    void click() { cout << "windows system\n"; }
};

// concrete implementation
class LinuxButtonImpl : public ButtonImpl {
    public:
    void click() { cout << "linux system\n"; }
};

// abstraction
class Button {
    public:
    Button(ButtonImpl* buttonImpl) : m_buttonImpl{ buttonImpl } {}
    virtual void click() = 0;
    protected:
    ButtonImpl* m_buttonImpl;
};

// concrete abstraction
class ToggleButton : public Button {
    public: 
    ToggleButton(ButtonImpl* buttonImpl) : Button(buttonImpl) {};
    void click() {
        m_buttonImpl->click();
        if(state) {
            cout << "Push\n";
            state = 0;
        } else {
            cout << "Pop\n";
            state = 1;
        }
    }
    private:
    bool state;
};

// concrete abstraction
class PushButton : public Button {
    public: 
    PushButton(ButtonImpl* buttonImpl) : Button(buttonImpl) {};
    void click() {
        m_buttonImpl->click();
        cout << "Push\n";
        cout << "Pop\n";
    }
};
```

I'm constantly thinking that both examples are somehow correct with structure of this pattern, and in my opinion with its description. But I cannot find any proper exaplanation to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example looks like plain old composition. Although the `Button` class is labelled as an abstraction, it is actually a concrete class; so concretion *has a* abstraction.

In the Bridge Pattern, the "bridge" relationship is between two abstractions, where high-level abstraction *has a* low-level abstraction. That's what's portrayed in the second example.

The terminology gets confusing, because what the pattern calls the "implementor" is also an abstraction: it's the low-level abstraction which the high-level abstraction uses in its implementations.

A bridge connects two separate inheritance hierarchies using composition. The two hierarchies vary independently through separate sets of subclasses. The second example has two separate sets of subclasses. The first example does not.

Comment: But from what i can read here:
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/bridge
so called "abstraction" is not exactly an interface for base classes. From above link I assume that first example is also correct (because subslassing is not needed for "abstraction" and if it exists it's some kind of extension for base class (and not an specific implementation of non existing object). Or is this not correct?

Comment: I think the linked article is pretty good (though not perfect as I've commented [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67913243/1371329)). I don't think I'm disagreeing with it in this answer. The Bridge Pattern incorporates two separate inheritance hierarchies, "so that the two can vary independently." Without two hierarchies, there is nothing to vary independently. So two are required.

Comment: Just by having composition, isn't it possible to vary them indepenently? Like isn't it a whole concept of prefer composition over inheritance because of loose coupling which is achieved with it? Isn't the thing that "two can vary independently" strongly connected to open/closed principle? I mean you rely on a statement that to vary "composition" and "implementation" independently you have to have two hierarchies, but I'm thinking that the same can be achieved just with composition.

Comment: If you're suggesting that every occurrence of composition is the Bridge pattern, it is not. Give the GoF a little bit of credit. They didn't write an entire chapter in their book just to say it's the same thing as composition.

Comment: sure, so like you said it's important to have two hierarchies right? I was just asking if isn't it possible to vary two classes independently while having only composition, because i thought it's possible :).