# Code Snippet : Bridge Pattern or Strategy Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

The following code is an example of Strategy Design Pattern or Bridge Design Pattern.
If Strategy , why not Bridge and vice-versa. I am quite confused after reading different articles and comments. Both patterns appear to have similar UMLs.

```
public interface IDriveStrategy
{
    void Drive();
}

public class NormalDriveStrategy : IDriveStrategy
{
    public void Drive(){    }
}

public class SportsDriveStrategy : IDriveStrategy
{
    public void Drive(){    }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    private readonly IDriveStrategy _driveStrategy;
    public Vehicle(IDriveStrategy driveStrategy)
    {
        _driveStrategy = driveStrategy;
    }
    public void Engine(){   }
    public void Display(){  }
    public void PerformDrive()
    {
        _driveStrategy.Drive();
    }
}

public class GoodsVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public GoodsVehicle() : base(new NormalDriveStrategy())
    {
    }
}

public class SportVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public SportVehicle() : base(new SportsDriveStrategy())
    {
    }
}

public class OffRoadVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public OffRoadVehicle() : base(new SportsDriveStrategy())
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this related post will help: [what-is-the-difference-between-the-bridge-pattern-and-the-strategy-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464524/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bridge-pattern-and-the-strategy-pattern), according to the accepted answer, the UML is the same for each pattern.

Comment: @RyanWilson , Thank you but upon reading that post only, I came to this code/design confusion.

Comment: Also see: [Bridge pattern - two examples comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71965704/1371329).

Comment: I would call the example here neither a Bridge nor Strategy, but just plain old composition.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), strategy is a behavioral pattern, while bridge is a structural pattern. So both of them can exist side by side.

Comment: @jaco0646, I think you should also go through the link RyanWilson shared to have a better understanding.

Comment: The Internet in general (and Wikipedia in particular) has for years popularized complete and utter nonsense about design patterns. Unfortunately, that nonsense spreads to many highly-voted threads and posts on SO. @RyanWilson happens to have found one, as was pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464524/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bridge-pattern-and-the-strategy-pattern#comment65036879_464549).

Comment: @jaco0646 Here's something not Wikipedia that says the same, the UML is the same for Bridge and Stategy - [oodesign](https://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern) - "Strategy and Bridge
Both of the patterns have the same UML diagram. But they differ in their intent since the strategy is related with the behavior and bridge is for structure. Further more, the coupling between the context and strategies is tighter than the coupling between the abstraction and implementation in the bridge pattern."

Comment: @RyanWilson, that's one more example from, "The Internet in general". It could easily have been copied from the errant Wikipedia article around the same time. That happens a lot. I'm not casting any blame here. The amount of misinformation on design patterns is truly incredible. There are far more misleading and blatantly incorrect articles than accurate ones. It's no wonder developers are confused. Ultimately, the only way to ensure you're reading what the authors intended is to read the GoF book. Bridge UML is on page 153. Strategy UML is on page 316. They are not the same.